# ColdFusion "Yes" eq "True"; "No" eq "False

Tags: coldfusion

Why is it ?

```
<cfif "yes" eq "true">

Yes equals true.

<cfelse>

Yes does not equal true.

</cfif>
```

The page outputs.
"Yes equals true."

Comment: A five second search for: coldfusion "yes" equal "true" turned up: http://www.houseoffusion.com/cfdocs1/cfmx/Developing_ColdFusion_MX_Applications_with_CFML/Variables6.html

Answer (score 13):

Chris' and Keshav's answers are correct, ColdFusion converts the values. Here is the official documentation on ColdFusion data conversions.

[Conversion between types](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fc3.html)

```
Value     As Boolean     As number     As date-time     As string

"Yes"     True           1             Error            "Yes"

"No"      False          0             Error            "No"

True      True           1             Error            "Yes"

False     False          0             Error            "No"
```

Answer (score 10):

ColdFusion has dynamic variable types,  and does a few odd conversions at runtime, strings can be used as booleans,  dates and numbers without casting them which has both advantages and disadvantages.

if you need to do a simple string comparison you can use the built in compare() function.

Ben Nadel gives a good summary of string comparison options here - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/236-ColdFusion-String-Comparison-Compare-vs-Equals-vs-CompareTo-.htm

Answer (score 3):

You have to be very careful with the true/false comparisons. They should be simple, but sometimes, depending on how you write your code, the evaluations of TRUE/FALSE may be different. By pretty much every definition, FALSE will always be bitwise 0 (and No in CF). And TRUE will be bitwise 1, but also Yes and any non-0 number. So 42 is still TRUE. And -1 is still TRUE (special thanks MS Access Yes/No datatypes :-p).

Since FALSE is always 0 (or NO or FALSE), it's usually better to check for NOT FALSE or NEQ 0 than it is to check for TRUE. However, even with that, you still have watch out. Determine what you want to consider TRUE and do a full evaluation for that. ColdFusion sometimes casts TRUE and FALSE variables differently. Look at the results of the following code:

(thanks to Bert Dawson and Jamie Jackson for their querySim script.)

```
<!--- set up the fake query: --->
<cfscript>
/**
 * Accepts a specifically formatted chunk of text, and returns it as a query object.
 * v2 rewrite by Jamie Jackson
 * 
 * @param queryData      Specifically format chunk of text to convert to a query. (Required)
 * @return Returns a query object. 
 * @author Bert Dawson (bert@redbanner.com) 
 * @version 2, December 18, 2007 
 */
function querySim(queryData) {
    var fieldsDelimiter="|";
    var colnamesDelimiter=",";
    var listOfColumns="";
    var tmpQuery="";
    var numLines="";
    var cellValue="";
    var cellValues="";
    var colName="";
    var lineDelimiter=chr(10) & chr(13);
    var lineNum=0;
    var colPosition=0;

    // the first line is the column list, eg "column1,column2,column3"
    listOfColumns = Trim(ListGetAt(queryData, 1, lineDelimiter));

    // create a temporary Query
    tmpQuery = QueryNew(listOfColumns);

    // the number of lines in the queryData
    numLines = ListLen(queryData, lineDelimiter);

    // loop though the queryData starting at the second line
    for(lineNum=2;  lineNum LTE numLines;  lineNum = lineNum + 1) {
        cellValues = ListGetAt(queryData, lineNum, lineDelimiter);

        if (ListLen(cellValues, fieldsDelimiter) IS ListLen(listOfColumns,",")) {
            QueryAddRow(tmpQuery);
            for (colPosition=1; colPosition LTE ListLen(listOfColumns); colPosition = colPosition + 1){
                cellValue = Trim(ListGetAt(cellValues, colPosition, fieldsDelimiter));
                colName   = Trim(ListGetAt(listOfColumns,colPosition));
                QuerySetCell(tmpQuery, colName, cellValue);
            }
        } 
    }
    return( tmpQuery );
}
</cfscript>

<!--- populate the fake query --->    
<cfscript>
fakeQuery = querySim('
testID , isThisTruthy
1 | TRUE
2 | FALSE
3 | YES
4 | NO
5 | 1
6 | 0
7 | -1
8 | 42
');
</cfscript>
<!--- End of the fake query setup --->

<!--- Dump the fakeQuery so we can see what we've got. --->
<cfdump var="#fakeQuery#" label="fakeQueryInfo" />

<!--- 
    Not really necessary since the query is created above. Just included for 
    clarity, as everything above this line can really be ignored if connecting 
    to a real query. 
--->
<cfquery name="truthyCheck" dbtype="query">
    SELECT testID, isThisTruthy
    FROM fakeQuery
</cfquery>

<!--- Begin the truthy statements. --->
<br/><br/>
<strong>cfif isThisTruthy >></strong> 
<!--- 
    This one has an implicit evaluation of TRUE or FALSE that seems to be based on a
    broader (and more accurate) definition of what should be TRUE or FALSE. However,
    it's much less clear in what you're trying to do. 
--->
<br/>
<cfoutput query="truthyCheck">
    #testID#: #isThisTruthy# | <cfif isThisTruthy>True<cfelseif NOT isThisTruthy>False<cfelse>NULL</cfif> <br/>
</cfoutput>
<br/><br/>

<!--- 
    The rest of these appear to actually evaluate down to a bit (using the standard
    1,0,YES,NO,TRUE,FALSE definitions) and then they do an integer comparison. This 
    may not be completely what you're looking for.
--->
<strong>cfif isThisTruthy IS TRUE >></strong>
<br/>
<cfoutput query="truthyCheck">
    #testID#: #isThisTruthy# | <cfif isThisTruthy IS TRUE>True<cfelseif isThisTruthy IS NOT TRUE>False<cfelse>NULL</cfif> 
    <!--- 1 IS 1 IS TRUE, but -1 IS 1 IS FALSE. --->
    <br/>
</cfoutput>
<br/><br/>
<strong>cfif isThisTruthy EQ 1 >></strong>
<br/>
<cfoutput query="truthyCheck">
    #testID#: #isThisTruthy# | <cfif isThisTruthy EQ 1>True<cfelseif isThisTruthy NEQ 1>False<cfelse>NULL</cfif> 
    <!--- 1 EQ 1 IS TRUE, but -1 EQ 1 IS FALSE. --->
    <br/>
</cfoutput>
<br/><br/>
<strong>cfif isThisTruthy NEQ 0 >></strong>
<br/>
<cfoutput query="truthyCheck">
    #testID#: #isThisTruthy# | <cfif isThisTruthy NEQ 0>True<cfelseif isThisTruthy EQ 0>False<cfelse>NULL</cfif> 
    <!--- 1 NEQ 0 and -1 NEQ 0 both evaluate to the same. --->
    <br/>
</cfoutput>
<br/><br/>
<strong>cfif isThisTruthy NEQ FALSE >></strong>
<br/>
<cfoutput query="truthyCheck">
    #testID#: #isThisTruthy# | <cfif isThisTruthy NEQ FALSE>True<cfelseif isThisTruthy EQ FALSE>False<cfelse>NULL</cfif> 
    <!--- 1 NEQ 0 and -1 NEQ 0 both evaluate to the same. --->
    <br/>
</cfoutput>
```

You'll get:

**cfif isThisTruthy >>** 
1: TRUE | True 
2: FALSE | False 
3: YES | True 
4: NO | False 
5: 1 | True 
6: 0 | False 
7: -1 | True *<--- Technically correct*
8: 42 | True *<--- Technically correct*

**cfif isThisTruthy IS TRUE >>** 
1: TRUE | True 
2: FALSE | False 
3: YES | True 
4: NO | False 
5: 1 | True 
6: 0 | False 
7: -1 | False  *<--- Technically incorrect*
8: 42 | False  *<--- Technically incorrect*

**cfif isThisTruthy EQ 1 >>** 
1: TRUE | True 
2: FALSE | False 
3: YES | True 
4: NO | False 
5: 1 | True 
6: 0 | False 
7: -1 | False *<--- Technically incorrect* 
8: 42 | False *<--- Technically incorrect*

**cfif isThisTruthy NEQ 0 >>** 
1: TRUE | True 
2: FALSE | False 
3: YES | True 
4: NO | False 
5: 1 | True 
6: 0 | False 
7: -1 | True *<--- Technically correct*
8: 42 | True *<--- Technically correct*

**cfif isThisTruthy NEQ FALSE >>** 
1: TRUE | True 
2: FALSE | False 
3: YES | True 
4: NO | False 
5: 1 | True 
6: 0 | False 
7: -1 | True *<--- Technically correct* 
8: 42 | True *<--- Technically correct*

Comment: Here's a fairly succinct article about how ColdFusion handles truth.

http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/2/5/Booleans.and.Coldfusion

Answer (score 2):

In ColdFusion "yes" and "true" both are converted  to  numerical value  1 when it is used as a expression

Answer (score 1):

yes, 1 and true are the same thing in coldFusion. As presented in this link:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fd0.html

Answer (score 0):

In coldfusion, "yes" and "true" are interpreted as bit(1) likewise "no" and "false" are interpreted as bit(0),so "yes" and "true" are equal. in same way

```
<cfif 1 eq "true">

Yes equals true.

</cfif>
```